# remove second segment in url for entry listings

Tags: templates, url, url-title, template-routes

Currently using `{url_title_path='blog/blog-entry}` for listing entries, but URL outputs `/blog/blog-entry/listing-title`. I'd like the URL to be `/blog/listing-title`. Can I do this using routes? What's best way to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

just use a href="blog/{url_title}" however, you'd have to add some segment checking in your blog template like {if segment_2 == ''}show overview{if:else}Show post{/if}

Comment: so essentially use the same template for both blog listings and single blog listing?

Comment: Yeah. if you're on EE2, you might wanna use switchee for those if statements. In EE3 just use native if statements. However, switchee can still be handy with pagination and edge cases